# How to join two faces with bevel?

Tags: modeling, bevel

Hi I'm trying to model this piece of the monitor

[image: https://imgur.com/METduBr]

Which i need to generate a Bevel between two faces (i think), but i don't know how to do it. I already tried to generate a face between the two to join and bevel it without luck.

[image: https://imgur.com/kaEkoEt]

[image: https://imgur.com/n5YgYhJ]

How should i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bevel *Edges*, not faces.

**How to:**
1) Remove unnecessary geometry (to prevent ugly topology later)
2) Bevel the edges
3) Finish your geometry
4) You're done.

**1) Delete faces**
Remove unnecessary faces with *Delete > Faces*, to prevent n-gons.

[image]

**2) Bevel edges**
Select your edges and bevel them.
Adjust width and number of segments as you need.

[image]
[image]

**3) Finish your mesh**.
To create a new face Press <kbd>F</kbd> or go to *Vertex > New face from vertices*
Keep quads where you can.
Add some new edges like I did :).

[image]

**4) You're done.**
Result with a *Bevel modifier* and a *Subdivision modifier* on top.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Very useful! 

To mantain topology, you added some vertex. Right?  How do you align those with the bevel? So the edge is at 90° [image](https://imgur.com/QqyNSBr)

Comment: Hello :). Perfect alignment isn't important here, it's just a flat face. But if you want it *perfect*, enable *absolute grid snap* (in the Snap menu) and use the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Why to fix something that is not broken? Life is short :)

- create from top and bottom faces n-gons (F)
- and Bevel (cmd+B)

[image]

- Bevel Modifier + Smooth Shading + Properties Editor > Object Data > Normals >  Auto Smooth

[image]