# How to make a shade sail/Sun sail?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I am trying to make a shade sail with two lower points (for water) for a client in blender, this is basically what i need to do.[image]

[image]

I've tried proportional editing but it is ineffective and very unsmooth. A cloth simulation with pinned corners doesn't work either. I am relatively new to blender and would appreciate the help :)
Thank you!

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205507/add-deflection-in-middle-of-edge-catenary-curve

Comment: Define why cloth simulation "doesn't work" as simulation is an often used way to obtain that.

Comment: This is because there it becomes "saggy". Maybe there is a way to apply tension to the pinned corners? I'm sorry, I'm very new.

Comment: You need to add a vertex group and set the vertices you want to stay out of the simulation as pinned in the simulation settings

Answer (score 4):

The cloth solution referenced by @batFINGER works for me:

[image]

Starting with the two (nearly) straight edges, first, *Bridge Edge Loops* with settings something like these:

[image]

.. and you're nearly there. A bit of *Vertex > Smooth*-ing on the internal vertices might do. But if you want to, you can finish the stretch with a quick Cloth sim, as shown on the right, above, with settings very similar to those provided as 'Tent' in the referenced answer, and the straight edges pinned throughout, rather than just the corners.

[image]

[image]

(the sim runs to stability in about 30 frames, in the provided .blend)

Answer (score 1):

[image]I assume that you have used a big plane with 4 verticies. Subdivide the plane and use proportional editing (press the letter O on the keyboard). This would be a possibility, otherwise you could also use a lattice modifier on the square with the corresponding lattice. But keep in mind, so or so you have to subdivide the square.

The lattice approach:

[image]

Select lattice and...
[image]

after the steps, move the lattice verticies around in edit mode

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately proportional editing doesn't look natural and in my opinion is hard to work with.

Answer (score 1):

As Jack Pillawa says you can do it with a *Lattice* modifier:

- Subdivide your plane, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

- Create a lattice (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), give it a *Resolution* of 3/3/1, scale it in *Object* mode so that it fits the plane size:

[image]

- Give your plane a *Lattice* modifier with the lattice as *Object*. Twist the lattice in order to deform the plane. You can create shapekeys for your lattice if you want to keep its basic flat shape:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try that.